# Hiding Rows with For Loop Over Range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have some data that looks like the following (new user so can't directly embed):

[image: DataExample 1]

I'm aiming to hide any row that shows "#Missing" or 0 across all month columns. So from the attached picture, the first three rows would never be hidden, but as of right now, the 4th row would be hidden as there are only "#Missing" and 0 values.

I've done a good bit of perusing through older posts and found a few similar questions, but nothing that quite solves my niche issue (it seems niche). That's all to say please forgive me if this has been solved elsewhere, I just couldn't find it.

Here is my starting point, which may be wildly off-base. I feel like this should be a relatively easy solution, but not totally sure:

```
Sub RowHider()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("I12:T10000")
    If c.Value = "#Missing" Or 0 Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Exit For
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `If c.Value = "#Missing" Or c.Value = 0 Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, using `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`:

```
Sub RowHider()

Dim c As Range
Dim rngToHide As Range

For Each c in Range("I12:T10000").Rows
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(c,"<>0",c,"<>#Missing") = 0 Then
        If rngToHide Is Nothing Then
            Set rngToHide = c
        Else
            Set rngToHide = Union(rngToHide, c)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rngToHide Is Nothing Then
    rngToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Note that this will not hide rows that are entirely blank, but can be adjusted to if needed.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want an idea of how this works in practice, put `=COUNTIFS(I12:T12,"<>0",I12:T12,"<>#Missing")=0` in a blank column in row 12 and drag down... any row that is `TRUE` is a row that'll be hidden.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, just applied this on one of my Uni assignment, worked perfectly, initially got an error, because `then` was missing after 0, adding it worked out. Thank you very much for all the knowledge inputs!